# How do I run a python whl endpoint from command line

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, python-wheel

how do I run the main function (or any endpoint) of a packaged python .whl file.
For example I have created the package with:

```
entry_points={'group_1': ['run=__main__:main']},
```

and there is a file `\__main__.py` with function `main()`.

I tried to run the command `> python mypack.whl`
and I was expecting it to run the main module.
But I got an error: `can't find '__main__' module in whl`

Comment: A python wheel is basically a zip file. You can unzip it and then run the main file. [more info](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/#what-is-a-python-wheel).

Comment: In which top-level importable package is the `__main__` module? -- Assuming we have a distribution package named `MyProject` containing `mypackage/__main__.py` meaning the top-level importable package is `mypackage` and so we can probably run something like `python MyProject-XYZ.whl/mypackage`.

Comment: `__main__.py` is on the top level

Comment: Also tried to install
`pip install dist/mypack.whl` . As expected, 
it shows in `pip freeze` as _mypack_ .
But when I run 
`python -m mypack`
is says module not found

Comment: As far as I know, you can not have `__main__.py` at the top level, it does not make sense, such a `__main__.py` only makes sense as part of an importable package.